# Migrating from SVN to CA Harvest SCM?

Tags: svn

We are trying to migrate source code from SVN to CA Harvest SCM. We know how to move the code but we are unable to migrate the history, which is required. 
How can this be done?

Is a migration tool needed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, history of repository changes can't be migrated easily. Since both SVN and Harvest have different database schema, it would be tough to do it without a migration tool.